# MYSQL trigger insertion and updation errors : MySQL error 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, triggers, assertion

I have 4 tables which look like....

```
 CREATE TABLE `Faculty` (
 `FID` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `Name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `DOB` date NOT NULL,
 `Sem` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
 `Section` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
 `Subject Code` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
 `Dep` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 `Hours Taken` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Student` (
 `USN` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `DOB` date NOT NULL,
 `Dep` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 `SEM` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `Class` varchar(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Student Attendance` (
`USN` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`Subject Code` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
`Attendance` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`Absent Days` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Subjects` (
`Subject` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`Subject Code` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
`Dep` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
`Sem` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now I needed to make sure that the number of hours that a student (`Student Attendance`.`Attendance`) has attended aren't greater than the number of hours the faculty member has taken (`Faculty`.`Hours Taken`) for that particular subject (`Subject Code`). So I wrote a trigger to check to check on insertion and updation if the above condition is satisfied.

If the number of hours(`Student Attendance`.`Attendance`) are greater then I have set the `Student Attendance`.`Attendance` to some String. I'm hoping that this will work as an assertion and give me an error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `HoursCheckonInsert` BEFORE INSERT ON `Student 
Attendance`
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.Attendance= IF(
( Select k.USN, s.`Subject Code`,f.`Hours Taken`,s.Attendance
   From Faculty f, `Student Attendance` s, Student k
   where s.`Subject Code` = f.`Subject Code` AND k.SEM = f.Sem AND k.Class=f.Section AND s.USN=k.USN AND 
   NEW.Attendance < f.`Hours Taken` OR NEW.Attendance = f.`Hours Taken`
 ),

NEW.Attendance,
'abcdef'
)

CREATE TRIGGER `HoursCheckonUpdate` BEFORE UPDATE ON `Student Attendance
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.Attendance= IF(
(Select k.USN, s.`Subject Code`,f.`Hours Taken`,s.Attendance
 From Faculty f, `Student Attendance` s, Student k
 where NEW.`Subject Code`=f.`Subject Code` AND  NEW.USN=k.USN AND 
NEW.USN=s.USN AND k.SEM=f.Sem AND k.Class=f.Section AND k.DEP=f.DEP
AND (NEW.Attendance < f.`Hours Taken` OR NEW.Attendance = f.`Hours Taken`)
 ),
NEW.Attendance,
'abcdef'
 )
```

When I try to insert a value into the Student Attendance, I get this error:

```
INSERT INTO `Student Attendance` (`USN`, `Subject Code`, `Attendance`, `Absent Days`) VALUES ('1KS15BT001', '15BT44', '0', '0');

Error: 
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

I'm new to triggers in MySQL.

Comment: I do not understand the selects withing the if.

Comment: I'm basically joining the 3 tables using the 3 conditions in the where clause and then I've added extra conditions to check whether the new added attendance is lesser than or equal to the Hours taken. Which columns are selected doesn't matter.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes it does matter what columns you are selecting. See the error message.

Comment: I just realised that theres an error in the select statement. I'll update the select statement. Please tell me if there's something else wrong with it.

Comment: Why would it matter which columns the select statement is selecting? The IF  statement will only check if any rows are returned or not. And depending on that take an action. Isn't that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Nope, that's not how it works. See the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's `IF()` function expects a *scalar expression* as its first argument. A scalar expression means it must be one column, and at most one row.

The subquery you use has four columns, and some unknown number of rows.

From your comments, it sounds like you're just interested in whether there are zero or more than zero rows matching the condition. You're right, it doesn't matter what columns you select—if you're using an `EXISTS` predicate to test the subquery instead of returning the result of the subquery in a scalar expression.

You should use the `EXISTS` predicate for what you want to do. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

```
CREATE TRIGGER `HoursCheckonInsert` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `Student Attendance`
FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.Attendance = IF(
    EXISTS(
      SELECT *
      FROM Faculty AS f
      JOIN `Student Attendance` AS s ON s.`Subject Code` = f.`Subject Code`
      JOIN Student AS k ON k.SEM = f.Sem AND k.Class=f.Section AND k.uSN = s.USN
      WHERE NEW.Attendance <= f.`Hours Taken`),
    NEW.Attendance,
    'abcdef');
```

Then it really doesn't matter what columns you put in the select-list. I show using `SELECT *` above. It doesn't matter, because `EXISTS` is only checking for the presence of any matching rows, and it won't have a result set at all—only the boolean for whether there are zero or more than zero rows.

You should also use `JOIN` syntax instead of the obsolete comma-style syntax for joins. I show that in the example above.

Comment: Thank you @BillKarwin. It's perfect. I decided to replace the String with NULL and set the Attendance attribute to NOT NULL. Because if I use the String as before for some reason it directly replaces it with 0 in the Attendance column.